# C++ return an object with constant member variables -- assignment operator implicitly deleted

Tags: c++, return-value, assignment-operator

```
struct MyStruct {
   const int a, b; 
   MyStruct(int a, int b): a(a), b(b) {}
}

map<int, MyStruct> m; 

m[2] = MyStruct(3, 4); // this would fail. Of course I can use m.insert( .... )
MyStruct t = m[2]; // this would not compile, because there is no assignment operator.
```

I will get below compilation error.

```
[assignment operator] is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

How do I get around this problem? I want to have constant member variables to avoid future accidental modification

Comment: `MyStruct t = m[2];` should use the copy constructor and not the assignment operator.  this is called [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Comment: What you can do is not make the member variable const but instead make them private.  Then have functions to access them.  And not have functions that allow them to be updated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The error message you show comes from the line `m[2] = MyStruct(3,4);`. However you have already correctly noted that that line fails, and you also correctly note that you can use `m.insert` instead.   The line `MyStruct t = m[2];` is an error but for a completely different reason that has nothing to do with const variables

Comment: `operator[]` cannot be used with a map where the mapped-type does not have a default constructor, because it needs to create a new entry if one didn't exist.  You will have to look up this map using `m.find` .

Answer (score 0):

There is an auto-generated copy constructor that will be equivalent to

```
MyStruct(MyStruct &s): a(s.a), b(s.b) {}
```

Use it to create the copy thusly:

```
MyStruct t(m[2]);
```

Comment: As Nathan Oliver's comment points out, you may not even need to define the constructor. Just `MyStruct t(m[2]);` should be enough.

Comment: There is already an implicitly-generated copy constructor that does exactly what yours does (except that it can also bind to rvalues), so this change would make no improvement.

Comment: @M.M. The corrected assignment does answer the question, and I noted in my comment that there is an auto-generated constructor. I have update the answer with that.

Comment: Your suggested answer doesn't compile either, given OP's struct definition. (As suggested in my comment on the question, perhaps OP is not actually posting his real code though)